# Added CSS style not disappearing on reload in Chrome developer tools

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-developer-tools

I am working on some front end design, and while fiddling with some stuff in Chrome developer tools I added the following to the webpage I am working on:
[image]

Even after reloading (and emptying cache and hard reloading) this style persists, regardless of whether or not I have the developer tools open.

I am not sure where this style is coming from or why it refuses to quit!

Has anyone experience something similar and were able to figure out a solution?

EDIT: If it matters this is being applied to a table element

Comment: Have you tried opening up the webpage in incognito mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only two options really: either you defined the width: 100% as an inline style or it's being added via JS as an inline style.

Comment: Yes it was being added via JS as an inline style. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Happy coding.